Android cached Vue js in web view
The web view loads a webpage with a script tag to an app.js file.
Have forced the app.js file to reload by appending a random string like so app.js?v=1223.
That worked for iOS, but Android is still picking up the old content.
Is there any way to force clear clear the cache?
When does the cache expire?
